# Как форматировать SQL код в VS Code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, visual-studio-code, форматирование

Ищу способ/расширение, с помощью которого можно красиво отформатировать sql код (желательно PostgreSQL). Первостепенно, чтобы по сочетанию клавиш или через команду в Ctrl+Shift+P все служебные слова конвертировались в верхний регистр.

Например, чтобы такой код:

```
create table if not exists cities (id integer primary key, name varchar(255) not null);
select * from cities;
```

Стал таким:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
SELECT * FROM   cities;
```

Или таким:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities
  (
      id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  );
SELECT *
FROM cities;
```

Перепробовал несколько расширений, но не нашёл такого, у которого есть такой функционал.

Comment: `SQL Formatter` + `Shift+Alt+F`

Comment: @InDevX, я пробовал, он только расставляет код, но не меняет регистр зарезервированных слов, что мне тоже нужно.

Comment: Не знаю таких чтоб регистр меняли.. Можно свой написать для sql.. Но какой в этом смысл? С каких пор ключевые слова в sql стали чувствительны к регистру?

Comment: @InDevX, есть онлайн сервисы, которые делают как мне надо, но это опять же онлайн.
Да, sql не чувствителен к регистру, но, насколько я знаю, ключевые слова в sql принято писать в большом регистре, чтобы легче читать код.

Comment: Не вижу в этом никакого смысла, честно говоря. Да, согласен что принято, но на крупных проектах и не раз встречал запросы с нижним регистром. Нет никакого смысла "форматировать" sql код, если в проекте при этом куча дыр и костылей.. Хотите писать - пишите сами заглавными, это не трудно

Comment: В субд некоторых есть функция "prettify" которая форматирует код и меняет ключевые слова. Я вообще не вижу проблемы самому писать заглавными запросы, а в тех же фреймворках вообще можно функциями пользоваться, которые сами всё подставляют

Comment: @InDevX вроде бы опытный пользователь, а такое безумие пишете. "Пишите сами заглавными, это не трудно". Рука-лицо просто. Ну сходите, перепишите скрипт от африканского коллеги на 5000 строк. За это же зарплату дают =\ В целом, ответ в начале вы верный написали, вопрос только в выборе хорошего форматтера. Тут стоит дополнить ваш ответ только, что многие имеют возможность форматировать регистр, нужно только включить в настройках.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов первый раз голос прошлого услышал) Дополнять нечего ибо это не ответ бы, а про скрипты на 5к строк это вы забавно придумали

Comment: @InDevX ах, если бы) Вот прямо сейчас правлю вьюху на 2.5к строк. Я уж не говорю про PL/SQL пакеты. Привет вам со стороны разработки в БД :)
p.s. Вообще, я бы советовал людям не мучаться с VS Code и поставить DataGrip или IDE от этих же JetBrains под ООП язык с поддержкой SQL (платные версии).